# Получение Canvas из фрейма другого домена

Tags: javascript, canvas, cors

Пытаюсь получить **canvas** из фрейма, который находится на другом домене с помощью кода

```js
    // Получение элемента canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

// Отрисовка на canvas
const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

// Получение изображения в формате base64
const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

console.log("Base64 изображения:", base64Image);
```

Все мои попытки терпят неудачу потому что фрейм грузится из другого сайта. Доступа к которому нет. Спустя долгое время понял что все дело в CORS. Подскажите какие есть способы получить Canvas если нет доступа к коду? При отрисовке через сторонние инструменты вместо изображения просто черный фон. JS не видит структуру фрейма. Очень нужна помощь. Пытаюсь решить это уже недели 3. Нашел только способ это установка расширения, есть ли другие способы?

Comment: Что вы собираетесь сделать? Зачем вам это нужно? Может есть и другие решения.

Comment: Мне надо получить картинку canvas Hcaptcha подозреваю что есть windows.parent или post message для обмена информацией между фреймами, но к сожалению, не нашел